# Print error to a file

Tags: java, printwriter

I am printing to a file, but the output is not looking like the desired output. It's only showing one batter in the output, rather than all 3. I have tried moving the printwriter up, but that didn't produce the correct output as well. Is there anything else I can try or do in order for it print out the other two batters from the stats.txt file?

**My code**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class marioSlugger {
  public static int getStat(String letter, String stats) {
      int count = stats.length() - stats.replace(letter, "").length();

    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String hitsLeader = null;
    String walksLeader = null;
    String hitsByPitchLeader = null;
    String strikeoutsLeader = null;
    String battingAverageLeader = null;
    String obpLeader = null;
    int maxHits        = 0;
    int maxWalks       = 0;
    int maxHitsByPitch = 0;
    int maxStrikeouts  = 0;
    int maxBa          = 0;
    int maxobp         = 0;

    java.io.File file = new java.io.File("stats.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

    //Find out number for each category
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        String[] parts  = line.split(" ");
        int hits        = getStat("H", parts[1]);
        int outs        = getStat("O", parts[1]);
        int walks       = getStat("W", parts[1]);
        int hitsByPitch = getStat("P", parts[1]);
        int strikeouts  = getStat("K", parts[1]);
        int sacrifices  = getStat("S", parts[1]);
        int totalAtBats = hits + outs + strikeouts;
        int obptotal    = hits + outs + walks + hitsByPitch + strikeouts +sacrifices;
        int accuracy    = 1000;
        double ba = ((double)hits/(double)totalAtBats );
        double obp = (((double)hits + (double)walks + (double)hitsByPitch) / (double)obptotal);

        //System.out.println(parts[0]);                   
        //System.out.printf("BA: %.3f\n", ba);
        //System.out.printf("OB: .%d\r\n", (int)(obp * accuracy) );
        //System.out.println("H: " + hits);
        //System.out.println("BB: " + walks);
        //System.out.println("K: " + strikeouts);
        //System.out.println("HBP: " + hitsByPitch);
        //System.out.println("");

        if (hits > maxHits) {
            maxHits = hits;
            hitsLeader = parts[0];
        }


        if (walks > maxWalks) {
            maxWalks = walks;
            walksLeader = parts[0];
        }

        if (hitsByPitch > maxHitsByPitch) {
            maxHitsByPitch = hitsByPitch;
            hitsByPitchLeader = parts[0];
        }

        if (strikeouts > maxStrikeouts) {
            maxHits = hits;
            strikeoutsLeader = parts[0];
        }            

        if (ba > maxBa) {
            maxHits = hits;
            battingAverageLeader = parts[0];
        }

        if (obp > maxobp) {
            maxobp = (int) obp;
            obpLeader = parts[0];
        }

        //Create PrintWriter
        java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter("leaders.txt");

        //Print LEAGUE LEADERS to leaders.txt
        output.println(parts[0]);
        output.printf("BA: %.3f\r\n", ba);
        output.printf("OB: .%d\r\n", (int)(obp * accuracy) );
        output.println("H: " + hits);
        output.println("BB: " + walks);
        output.println("K: " + strikeouts);
        output.println("HBP: " + hitsByPitch);
        output.println("");
        output.println("LEAGUE LEADERS");
        output.println("BA: " + battingAverageLeader);
        output.println("OB%: " + obpLeader);
        output.println("H: " + hitsLeader);
        output.println("BB: " + walksLeader);
        output.println("K: " + strikeoutsLeader);
        output.println("HPB: " + hitsByPitchLeader);
        output.close();
    }

  }
}
```

**My Output**

```
Pudge
BA: 0.450
OB: .500
H: 9
BB: 2
K: 8
HBP: 1

LEAGUE LEADERS
BA: Pudge
OB%: Pudge
H: Piazza
BB: Griffey
K: Pudge
HPB: Griffey
```

**Desired Output Example**

```
Mario
BA: .455
OB%: .563
H: 5
BB: 3
K: 2
HBP: 1

Luigi
BA: .364
OB%: .533
H: 4
BB: 2
K: 3
HBP: 2

Toad
BA: .600
OB%: .833
H: 3
BB: 7
K: 0
HBP: 0

LEAGUE LEADERS
BA: Toad
H: Mario
BB: Toad
K: Toad
HBP: Luigi
```

**stats.txt**

```
Griffey HHOHOKWOHKSPOOWSHHWWWWWWW
Piazza OOHHHKPSOHOOHWWHOSSSHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
Pudge HHHHKOOHHHSWWHHOPKKKKKKK
```

Answer (score 0):

You're over-writing your output at each iteration of the while loop:

```
while (input.hasNextLine()) {

   java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter("leaders.txt");

    //Print LEAGUE LEADERS to leaders.txt
    output.println(parts[0]);
    output.printf("BA: %.3f\r\n", ba);
    output.printf("OB: .%d\r\n", (int)(obp * accuracy) );
    output.println("H: " + hits);
    output.println("BB: " + walks);
    output.println("K: " + strikeouts);
    output.println("HBP: " + hitsByPitch);
    output.println("");
    output.println("LEAGUE LEADERS");
    output.println("BA: " + battingAverageLeader);
    output.println("OB%: " + obpLeader);
    output.println("H: " + hitsLeader);
    output.println("BB: " + walksLeader);
    output.println("K: " + strikeoutsLeader);
    output.println("HPB: " + hitsByPitchLeader);
    output.close();
}
```

Try something like this instead.

```
// initialize this *outside* the while loop
java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter("leaders.txt");

while (input.hasNextLine()) {

    // Do the things...
    // ...

    // append output to the file.
    output.println(parts[0]);
    output.printf("BA: %.3f\r\n", ba);
    output.printf("OB: .%d\r\n", (int)(obp * accuracy) );
    output.println("H: " + hits);
    output.println("BB: " + walks);
    output.println("K: " + strikeouts);
    output.println("HBP: " + hitsByPitch);
    output.println("");

}

// *Now* print league leaders. 
output.println("LEAGUE LEADERS");
output.println("BA: " + battingAverageLeader);
output.println("OB%: " + obpLeader);
output.println("H: " + hitsLeader);
output.println("BB: " + walksLeader);
output.println("K: " + strikeoutsLeader);
output.println("HPB: " + hitsByPitchLeader);
output.close();  // Good to close the file. :)
```

Comment: That still only prints out one of the batters. Also, the variables are declared inside the while loop, and aren't working outside of it.

Comment: You may want to update your answer with what you tried. I'm not seeing the same issue as you.

Comment: Oh, whoopsie I didn't put it completely outside of the loop. Yes I was able to fix it with your help.

Comment: Awesome! :) If this answered your question, then go ahead and accept my answer so it'll get marked as 'answered'.